# dependency ‘stringr’ is not available for package ‘rgeos’

Tags: r, rgeos

Attempting to install rgeos package fails.  Detailed error logs as follows:-

```
> install.packages("rgeos", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
Installing package(s) into ‘/Users/calvin/R/x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0-library/2.14’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: dependency ‘stringr’ is not available
trying URL 'http://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib/rgeos_0.1-15.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 166974 bytes (163 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 163 Kb

ERROR: dependency ‘stringr’ is not available for package ‘rgeos’
* removing ‘/Users/calvin/R/x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0-library/2.14/rgeos’

The downloaded packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/4l/rd4wl50x52n504t2vzqskhhc0000gn/T/RtmppBNwSt/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("rgeos", repos = "http://R-Forge.R-project.org") :
  installation of package ‘rgeos’ had non-zero exit status
> install.packages("stringr", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
Installing package(s) into ‘/Users/calvin/R/x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0-library/2.14’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message:
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  package ‘stringr’ is not available (for R version 2.14.0)
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be some problem with installing the copy of rgeos from repos = "http://R-Forge.R-project.org".

I used the Singapore mirror and the installation worked out fine.

```
Installing package(s) into ‘/Users/calvin/R/x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0-library/2.14’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Loading Tcl/Tk interface ... done
also installing the dependencies ‘itertools’, ‘iterators’, ‘plyr’, ‘stringr’

trying URL 'http://cran.stat.nus.edu.sg/src/contrib/itertools_0.1-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 15595 bytes (15 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 15 Kb

trying URL 'http://cran.stat.nus.edu.sg/src/contrib/iterators_1.0.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 274267 bytes (267 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 267 Kb

trying URL 'http://cran.stat.nus.edu.sg/src/contrib/plyr_1.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 361576 bytes (353 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 353 Kb

trying URL 'http://cran.stat.nus.edu.sg/src/contrib/stringr_0.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 20551 bytes (20 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 20 Kb

trying URL 'http://cran.stat.nus.edu.sg/src/contrib/rgeos_0.1-15.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 171187 bytes (167 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 167 Kb

* installing *source* package ‘iterators’ ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices ...
*** tangling vignette sources ...
   ‘iterators.Rnw’ 
   ‘writing.Rnw’ 
** testing if installed package can be loaded

* DONE (iterators)
* installing *source* package ‘itertools’ ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices ...
** testing if installed package can be loaded

* DONE (itertools)
* installing *source* package ‘plyr’ ...
** libs
*** arch - x86_64
/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.4 -std=gnu99 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64  -I/opt/local/include    -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64 -c loop-apply.c -o loop-apply.o
/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.4 -std=gnu99 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64  -I/opt/local/include    -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64 -c split-numeric.c -o split-numeric.o
/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.4 -std=gnu99 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/opt/local/lib -o plyr.so loop-apply.o split-numeric.o -L/opt/local/lib/R/lib/x86_64 -lR
installing to /Users/calvin/R/x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0-library/2.14/plyr/libs/x86_64
** R
** data
**  moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices ...
** testing if installed package can be loaded

* DONE (plyr)
* installing *source* package ‘stringr’ ...
** package ‘stringr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices ...
** testing if installed package can be loaded

* DONE (stringr)
* installing *source* package ‘rgeos’ ...
** package ‘rgeos’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
geos-config: geos-config
GEOS: 3.3.0
CPPFLAGS: -I/opt/local/include
LIBS: -L/opt/local/lib -lgeos
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
*** arch - x86_64
/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.4 -std=gnu99 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64 -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I"/Users/calvin/R/x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0-library/2.14/sp/include"   -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64 -c gpc_geos.c -o gpc_geos.o
/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.4 -std=gnu99 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64 -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I"/Users/calvin/R/x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0-library/2.14/sp/include"   -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64 -c init.c -o init.o
/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.4 -std=gnu99 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64 -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I"/Users/calvin/R/x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0-library/2.14/sp/include"   -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64 -c local_stubs.c -o local_stubs.o
/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.4 -std=gnu99 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64 -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I"/Users/calvin/R/x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0-library/2.14/sp/include"   -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64 -c rgeos.c -o rgeos.o
/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.4 -std=gnu99 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64 -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I"/Users/calvin/R/x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0-library/2.14/sp/include"   -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64 -c rgeos_R2geos.c -o rgeos_R2geos.o
/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.4 -std=gnu99 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64 -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I"/Users/calvin/R/x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0-library/2.14/sp/include"   -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64 -c rgeos_bbox.c -o rgeos_bbox.o
/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.4 -std=gnu99 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64 -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I"/Users/calvin/R/x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0-library/2.14/sp/include"   -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64 -c rgeos_buffer.c -o rgeos_buffer.o
/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.4 -std=gnu99 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64 -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I"/Users/calvin/R/x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0-library/2.14/sp/include"   -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64 -c rgeos_coord.c -o rgeos_coord.o
/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.4 -std=gnu99 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64 -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I"/Users/calvin/R/x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0-library/2.14/sp/include"   -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64 -c rgeos_geos2R.c -o rgeos_geos2R.o
/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.4 -std=gnu99 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64 -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I"/Users/calvin/R/x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0-library/2.14/sp/include"   -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64 -c rgeos_misc.c -o rgeos_misc.o
/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.4 -std=gnu99 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64 -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I"/Users/calvin/R/x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0-library/2.14/sp/include"   -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64 -c rgeos_poly2nb.c -o rgeos_poly2nb.o
/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.4 -std=gnu99 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64 -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I"/Users/calvin/R/x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0-library/2.14/sp/include"   -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64 -c rgeos_predicate_binary.c -o rgeos_predicate_binary.o
rgeos_predicate_binary.c: In function 'rgeos_relate':
rgeos_predicate_binary.c:114: warning: passing argument 5 of 'rgeos_binpredfunc' from incompatible pointer type
rgeos.h:155: note: expected 'p_binpredfunc' but argument is of type 'char * (*)(struct GEOSContextHandle_HS *, const struct GEOSGeometry *, const struct GEOSGeometry *)'
rgeos_predicate_binary.c: In function 'rgeos_binpredfunc':
rgeos_predicate_binary.c:142: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast
rgeos_predicate_binary.c:162: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast
/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.4 -std=gnu99 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64 -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I"/Users/calvin/R/x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0-library/2.14/sp/include"   -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64 -c rgeos_predicate_unary.c -o rgeos_predicate_unary.o
/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.4 -std=gnu99 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64 -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I"/Users/calvin/R/x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0-library/2.14/sp/include"   -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64 -c rgeos_topology.c -o rgeos_topology.o
/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.4 -std=gnu99 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64 -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I"/Users/calvin/R/x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0-library/2.14/sp/include"   -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64 -c rgeos_topology_binary.c -o rgeos_topology_binary.o
/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.4 -std=gnu99 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64 -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I"/Users/calvin/R/x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0-library/2.14/sp/include"   -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64 -c rgeos_validate.c -o rgeos_validate.o
/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.4 -std=gnu99 -I/opt/local/lib/R/include -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/x86_64 -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I"/Users/calvin/R/x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0-library/2.14/sp/include"   -fPIC  -pipe -O2 -m64 -c rgeos_wkt.c -o rgeos_wkt.o
/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.4 -std=gnu99 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/opt/local/lib -o rgeos.so gpc_geos.o init.o local_stubs.o rgeos.o rgeos_R2geos.o rgeos_bbox.o rgeos_buffer.o rgeos_coord.o rgeos_geos2R.o rgeos_misc.o rgeos_poly2nb.o rgeos_predicate_binary.o rgeos_predicate_unary.o rgeos_topology.o rgeos_topology_binary.o rgeos_validate.o rgeos_wkt.o -L/opt/local/lib -lgeos -lgeos_c -L/opt/local/lib/R/lib/x86_64 -lR
installing to /Users/calvin/R/x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0-library/2.14/rgeos/libs/x86_64
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices ...
** testing if installed package can be loaded

* DONE (rgeos)

The downloaded packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/4l/rd4wl50x52n504t2vzqskhhc0000gn/T/RtmpoW3Gja/downloaded_packages’
```